# 120hz in 2D, what's the point?

Tags: pc, monitor

So I've been searching the internet for advice on my next PC/Console monitor purchase and come across a good deal on the LG D2342P-PN. It's LED, got all three connectors I want and even 3D in 120Hz, which I didn't want but why not have?!

Then, I read some reviews and the biggest simple complain I read is that this monitor does not support 120Hz in 2D. Last time I checked 60fps was the speed everyone wanted their games to run in, which is the same as refresh speed of most monitors, but now we're aiming for, presumably, 120fps? Or is it 60fps in 120Hz, that we want? But still, why? Therefore:

What are the advantages of running a monitor in 120Hz in 2D? (general use, films and games)

I understand why 120fps in 3D is good (single eye flickering, whatever it's called, which in effect produces 60fps), but in 2D? Please someone explain! Cheers.

Comment: Please don't cross post to multiple sites - http://superuser.com/questions/374976/120hz-in-2d-whats-the-point

Comment: Sure, I wasn't sure which one is the correct one. It's not purely about gaming nor hardware. Sorry.

Comment: Mods on one site can work with mods on other sites to migrate a question to the appropriate site. If you aren't sure where a question belongs, ask it just once, on the site you think is best, and it can be moved if it fits better somewhere else.

Comment: There is no such thing as LED monitor, not yet. There are simply TFT monitors with LED backlight. Backlight type doesn't mean much except energy efficiency (leds are better) and color accuracy (CCFLs are better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frames per second of the game is different to the refresh rate of the monitor.

Higher refresh rates on the monitor give you a more stable picture - regardless of whether that picture is being changed by the computer at 60 frames per second or 1. When monitors were cathode ray tubes it was definitely the case that you could see flickering at 60Hz or even higher refresh rates so a 120Hz monitor would effectively be "flicker free". With LCD and LED displays this is less of an issue, but going to 120Hz *could* be beneficial, but it's unlikely.

However, it's more likely that it's because the monitor is operating in 120Hz anyway regardless of the 2D/3D mode.

Comment: OK, so the 120Hz in 2D on a LED could be beneficial, but there is no evidence that it is? Why do people make such fuss about it in the reviews of this monitor I'd like to know. Are people just higher-number crazy, even if it doesn't bring any benefits with it?

Comment: You can tell the difference between 60Hz and 120Hz.  I don't know that it's a hardware selling difference, but you can tell.  The smoothness even just with normal desktop interaction is obvious.

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo - Er - that's what prompted the question in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisF Apologies, I closed this question as there's really no point in having answers on both. You might want to post this on SU.

Comment: CRT flickering is not a simple matter of refresh rate. CRT monitor have phosphor coating that glows after being hit by a beam and then some time after. So the flickering comes when refresh rate is slower than phosphor afterglow. You can have flicker-free CRT at 20Hz, it just won't look good with fast-paced action.